# OpenGL Fonts via Textured Quads

Tags: c++, opengl, fonts, opengl-es

I'm writing a small OpenGL application and I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement text, digits in particular. I'm just trying to display a four digit number, and I have pre-allocated rectangles where each digit should go (almost like a seven segment display). I just need to know the best way to "get" the digit into the rectangle. Would storing each digit into a texture atlas and then drawing the textures as quads be easiest? Would it scale to thousands of digits? How would I accomplish something like that?

Comment: I don't think you're using the word "just" correctly here, it sounds like you have no idea where to start, so it sounds much more like you need to just try "any" approach, not wait for the best (whatever "best" means)

Comment: This is way too broad. You may want to look at [freetype](http://www.freetype.org/) and [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/). I used both to implement simple font renderer in OpenGL.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the freetype library at all costs. I don't want to introduce another dependency for my project. I guess what I am looking for is just some advice on whether or not using textures to render text sounds sane or not.

Comment: Freetype is brilliant.  Don't make life hard for yourself by *not* using it.  The dependency is minimal (I have one class that uses it).  Once you've wrapped your head around how to get the bitmaps out of freetype, find a good bin packing algorithm to construct a texture (again one small class).  This is far better than making your project dependent upon a font, font size, single texture or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" (I would prefer to say "usual"...) way to implement text is to use Freetype if you want to use any kind of langage / font in your app and want perfect antialiasing.

Basically you use freetype to render characters (rendering is done via CPU not GPU) to a texture "font cache" then you draw one quad per character by sampling this font cache. This is actually rather complex because there are a lot of things to handle (what happens when the cache is full, do you need to cache a character in different sizes or accept some scaling, how to handle the fact that updating the texture cache can stall the GPU, how to dynamic or static batch to not have 1 draw call per character, and many other things ...).

Since you are doing a simple project and mostly want to display digits, I would advise you to load a bitmap containing the pre-rendered characters to a texture then draw a quad for each character, sampling the texture. You can find a tutorial [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/2d_texture_font/18002/) in which they use a texture like this :

[image]